# (jquery) Circle buttonset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I Have circle-shape buttonset (use in radio button) from jqueryUI?

as I get from jqueryUI, its shape is rectangle/square.

for example id I have 4 radio button
a b c d
I want every radio have circle shape

Comment: I thought radio buttons alreadt circle-shaped

Comment: Are you talkign about jQuery UI?

Comment: yes..JqueryUI..
@DenisErmolin don't you know radiobutton in buttonset?

Comment: @VickySantoso - can you show some snapshots? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the author is talking about [Button/Radio](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio) that generates `buttonset()` method. That's funny but I think the best option to make radio buttons generated with jQueryUI rounded is to add them a new CSS style similar to:

```
.rounded-corners {
  -moz-border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
```

Happy if that will help you with your non trivial problem :)